# How to uninstall MAAS

Tags: uninstall, maas

I accidentally selected the options to install MAAS on a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04. In order to remove the server/service, is it just a matter of "sudo apt-get remove maas"?

Comment: you can try it, it will tell you the packages it wants to remove before it removes them. some people would use sudo apt-get purge maas

Answer (score 2):

Right maas uninstalling:

```
sudo apt-get purge maas ; sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Answer (score 2):

To round out:

```
sudo apt-get purge maas maas-cli maas-cluster-controller  maas-common maas-dhcp maas-dns maas-region-controller python-django-maas python-maas-client python-maas-provisioningserver ; apt-get autoremove
```

Answer (score 2):

**The Best way is using :**

```
sudo maas init
```

Are you sure you want to initialize again (yes/no) [default=no]?

```
yes
```

Mode (all/region+rack/region/rack/none) [default=all]?

```
none
```

This will disconnect your MAAS from the running database.
Are you sure you want to disconnect the database (yes/no) [default=no]?

```
yes
```

MAAS and services should be stoped.

---

And to complete remove of bin:

```
snap remove maas maas-cli
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is yes that is the command to remove a program.

[image]

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto

It shouldn't remove any other dependancies, they are files other programs use.

Use purge to remove config files.

```
sudo apt-get purge maas
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I wasn't sure if there were any other packages installed along with it. I.e. maas-*.

FTR, purging ended up removing the user, group, vhost, and maas_longpoll user. I ran it after the remove command.

Comment: Do you want to accept your answer! It only takes a click.